# How can you reverse traverse through a C# collection?

Tags: c#, collections, reverse, traversal

Is it possible to have a `foreach` statement that will traverse through a Collections object in reverse order?

If not a `foreach` statement, is there another way?

Comment: Cringing at the comments and answers in this thread.  Reverse() is *not* a substitute for a for() loop, it has O(n) storage requirements.  The LINQ black box can be dangerous.

Comment: @Hans: Wrong.  `Reverse` will use `IList` if available.

Comment: @SLaks: where?  I don't see it.

Comment: @Hans: I take that back; it doesn't.  I wonder why.

Answer (score 29):

You can use a normal `for` loop backwards, like this:

```
for (int i = collection.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    var current = collection[i];
    //Do things
}
```

You can also use LINQ:

```
foreach(var current in collection.Reverse()) {
    //Do things
}
```

However, the normal `for` loop will probably be a little bit faster.

Comment: The `for` loop may be faster, but the LINQ is certainly clearer. I would therefore prefer the LINQ version.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't realize you could traverse through a collection with brackets... so i guess its just
for (int i = collections.Count; i >= 0; i--)... Ugh I'm a moron. Thanks.

Comment: @Sam F. No you are not! :-)

Comment: @jball: Iterating backwards in a for loop is somehow "unclear"?  Really?

Comment: @Sam F: Not all collections have random access (ie. brackets), so you're not wrong in any case. :)

Comment: Note that your first example only works if the Collection has an indexer; not all collections do. `Reverse` is the best option.

Comment: That username is genius.  I love the fact that everyone will address you as "Hey, moron"

Comment: @Kyte, @Randolpho: AFAIK, the only collections that don't have indexers are the intrinsically unordered ones (eg, Dictionary.ValuesCollection), which you shoudn't be reversing in the first place.

Comment: @Ed:  In this age of iterators and LINQ, for loops seem downright antiquated.

Comment: @SLaks: you left out `LinkedList`, which is ordered and reversible, but is not indexible.

Comment: @SLaks: I may be defiling the proper use of IEnumerable, but I tend to use them even on objects that have easy linear transversal but no random access. Say, data incoming from a network stream or a sequential-access file. (That last one was for homework, mind you.)

Comment: @SLaks: and as I go through them, there are `SortedDictionary`, `SortedSet`, and `Stack`, all of which are ordered and reversible, but not indexible. And that's just in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace... I could search for more...

Comment: @Ed Swangren, you really think the loop is as clear as the LINQ? The LINQ expresses in 1 line using an english verb as the method name what it will do. The `for` loop requires 2 lines, awareness of the bounds of the list, and succeeds in saying "reverse" via `--`. The LINQ is clearly more expressive.

Comment: I didn't look, but `Reverse()` is probably smart enough to use indexes if they are available. For instance, the LINQ `Count()` method is smart enough to access the `Length` or `Count` property if it exists, and to count the elements in the enumeration one-by-one only if no such property exists.

Comment: @SLaks: Reading back I realize I sound a little dickish with that; such was not my intent. I'm just trying to point out that it's best to use `Reverse` for the general case, since not every collection has an indexer.

Answer (score 7):

You could just call [Reverse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) on the collection.

```
foreach(var item in collection.Reverse()) { ... }
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a Reverse() on Collections<class> that was my first thought.

Comment: @Sam F: It's an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on any `IEnumerable<T>` (which includes `Collection<T>`), available from .NET 3.5 onwards. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx) for a list of all of them. If you're using .NET 3.5 or later you just need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file.

Comment: I suppose I should add a note - confusingly enough, Reverse() has a different meaning for IList<T> than it does for standard IEnumerable<T>.

IList<T>.Reverse() returns void so in order for my snippet to work, you'd have to say collection.AsEnumerable().Reverse().  Confusing business, that.

Comment: 48klocs, can you put the comment answer in the real answer....?  (the AsEnumerable()).   I almost gave up on the posted-answer before I read the magic comment.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using 3.5, looks like there is a Reverse() method in LINQ
That won't iterate through in reverse order, but would reverse the entire list, then you could do your foreach.

Or you could use a simple for statement:

```
for(int i = list.Count -1; i >= 0; --i)
{
   x = list[i];
}
```

Comment: You're asking for an `IndexOutOfBounds` error. Start at `i = count - 1`

Comment: "That won't iterate through in reverse order, but would reverse the entire list." This is untrue. Iterating in reverse order is *precisely* what the `Enumerable.Reverse<T>` extension method does. You may be thinking of `List<T>.Reverse`, which [confusingly has the same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828917/most-awkward-misleading-method-in-the-net-api/2829051#2829051).

Comment: @Greg, good catch, updated.

@Dan Tao, I was thinking of List<T>.Reverse.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, if the collection's an IEnumerable and therefore without random access, use System.Linq's IEnumerable.Reverse() method and apply forearch as usual.

```
using System.Linq;

foreach (var c in collection.Reverse()) {
}
```

Comment: Reverse is the only *viable* option for reverse iterating over a collection. Too many collections are not indexible.

Answer (score 2):

```
        List<string> items = new List<string> 
        { 
            "item 1", 
            "item 2",
            "item 3", 
            "item 4", 
        };
        lines.AsEnumerable().Reverse()
                            .Do(a => Console.WriteLine(a), ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message), () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"))
                            .Run();
```

[Reactive Extension for .NET 3.5/4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx)