# Reverse the order of a string list without using "List.Reverse()"

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> arrWords = new List<string>();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Type a word: ");
                string arrInput = Console.ReadLine();
                if (arrInput == "")
                {
                    break;
                }
                arrWords.Add(arrInput);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < arrWords.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arrWords.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (arrWords[i] > arrWords[j])
                    {
                        string temp = arrWords[i];
                        arrWords[i] = arrWords[j];
                        arrWords[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (string arrWord in arrWords)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arrWord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone show me how to reverse the order of string list without using (List.Reverse()).

For example:
 1. Cow
 2. Cat
 3. Dog
After Reverse:
 4. Dog
 5. Cat
 6. Cow

Just order by descending!

Comment: `myList = myList.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList()`? Why don´t you want to use `Reverse`? Can you use linq? Or what is your actual requirement?

Comment: reverse your loop.

Comment: Why is cow behind cat when ordering reversely?

Comment: Just do it only with for loop

Comment: Because I am reversing the order

Cow
Cat
Dog

Dog
Cat
Cow

Comment: this feels like  your homework

Comment: This is not my homework this is just like a challange for me by a friend.
I tried many things but it didn't work

Comment: Doesn't seem to be in the spirit of a challenge if you solicit an answer off the internet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you reverse traverse through a C# collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056155/how-can-you-reverse-traverse-through-a-c-sharp-collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int i = 0;
 int j = arrWords.Length - 1;
 while (i < j)
 {
     string temp = arrWords[i];
     objArray[i] = arrWords[j];
     objArray[j] = temp;
     i++;
     j--;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // 1. Cow 2. Cat 3. Dog After Reverse: 4. Dog 5. Cat 6. Cow
      List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Cow", "Cat", "Dog" };
      ReverseList(list);
    }

    private static void ReverseList(List<string> list)
    {
      int i = 0;
      int j = list.Count - 1;

      for (i = 0; i < list.Count / 2; i++, j--)
      {
        string temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[j];
        list[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
```